# Show the position and offset of all matches in elasticsearch/lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-highlight

I want to include start and end offset of matched term in search query using elasticsearch.

I am currently using search-highlight plugin in elasticsearch to retrieve position of matched term in result. 
However, I want to include the position of matched term in the query, too.
For example with this document indexed: "fox", and with this query: "fox is a fox". The expected result of matched terms in query would be [0,3] and [9, 12]. 
Any help would be helpful!